# How to use temporary table in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am creating a temporary table in a stored procedure like this:

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('#INSTL_PLAN_TEMP') IS NULL 
 BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE #INSTL_PLAN_TEMP(P_LOAN_ID INT,
                                   P_RECOVERY_TYPE VARCHAR(1),
                                   P_SEQ_NO INT,
                                   P_FROM_INSTL_NO INT)

     DROP TABLE #INSTL_PLAN_TEMP 
 END
```

After that I create a cursor on this table like

```
 DECLARE INSTL_PLAN_CUR CURSOR FOR
     SELECT P_RECOVERY_TYPE, P_LOAN_ID, P_SEQ_NO, P_FROM_INSTL_NO
     FROM INSTL_PLAN_TEMP
     WHERE P_LOAN_ID = @I_LOAN_ID
     ORDER BY P_LOAN_ID, P_SEQ_NO;
```

but in cursor statement it shows error

> *Invalid object name INSTL_PLAN_TEMP*

plz help I am new to SQL

Comment: You forgot the `#` in front of your tablename *(I assume you declare and use the cursor between the create and drop statement). On a sidenote, there's rarely a need to use cursors. We don't have enough information to give you alternatives but a set based approach is **much** faster.

Comment: `Create TABLE` is not required for temporary tables..

Comment: plz give me alternate solution

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: **of course** it is ....

Comment: @user1831355 - That depends on what you want to do with the cursor, as I've said, we don't have enough information to give you any advice on that.

Answer (score 1):

Three points I can see:

- You are creating the table `#INSTL_PLAN_TEMP` and very next statement you are dropping it.
- And, I think in the the cursor you should be using  `#INSTL_PLAN_TEMP` and not  `INSTL_PLAN_TEMP`
- Cursor should be defined as `@INSTL_PLAN_CUR CURSOR`

Note: Thanks Mohit for pointing out.

-Milind

Comment: Also, declaration of cursor is not correct.
Declare is as:
DECLARE @INSTL_PLAN_CUR CURSOR

Answer (score 1):

I think this will not work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#INSTL_PLAN_TEMP') IS NULL
```

If I'm not mistaken it will look like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#INSTL_PLAN_TEMP') IS NULL
```

Why drop after creation?

```
DROP TABLE #INSTL_PLAN_TEMP
```

This is the correct declaration:

```
DECLARE @INSTL_PLAN_CUR CURSOR FOR
   SELECT P_RECOVERY_TYPE, P_LOAN_ID, P_SEQ_NO, P_FROM_INSTL_NO
   FROM #INSTL_PLAN_TEMP
   WHERE P_LOAN_ID = @I_LOAN_ID
      ORDER BY P_LOAN_ID, 
              P_SEQ_NO;
```